# laravel 5.4, how to insert a timestamp (mysql)

Tags: mysql, laravel, timestamp, migration

In our laravel migrations, we insert static data which is required by the app (countries, currencies etc).

We are trying to insert a row with a timestamp field, but cant figure out how to set it to a specifid day/time.

We have tried time() and setting a standard date format, e.g:

```
DB::table('test')->insert(['id'=>1,'start_at'=>time(), 'end_at'=>'2050-01-01 00:00:00']);
```

Both timestamp columns end up with 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with Carbon `start_at'=>tCarbon::now()` don't forget to add `use Carbon\Carbon` at the top :)

Answer (score 3):

`time()` returns a Unix timestamp, but MySQL wants a YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss timestamp. You can use e.g. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` or try out [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

By the way, you also have a missing ' prior to `start_at`.

Answer (score 1):

with
Carbon:

```
$dt = Carbon::parse('2012-9-5 23:26:11');
var_dump($dt->timestamp);     //int(1346901971)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also let the DB server do the work:

```
'start_at'=>DB::raw('now()')
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found one solution (Carbon option given by Joel & Maraboc might be better)

```
$now= new DateTime;
$future = $now->add(new DateInterval('P20Y'));
DB::table('test')->insert(['id'=>1,'start_at'=>$now, 'end_at'=>$future]);
```